# How to format this string to DateTime in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

This is what I tried:

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
DateTime parsedDateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(reader.Value.ToString(),format, null, 
              System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime))
{
    return parsedDateTime;
}
```

where `reader.Value.ToString()` is

> 2017-05-01T00:00:000

Comment: What type is `reader.Value`?

Comment: And what doesn't work? What's not happening that you expect to happen?

Comment: :)) I expected to parse it and but it doesn't

Comment: You have an extra `0` at the end of your `reader.Value`. Of course it doesn't match your format.

Comment: It tried that also... with format ending in sss

Comment: @Vlado there is no `sss` [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). `ss0` would work if there's always a trailing zero.

Comment: As @DigiFriend said, you can't have seconds with 3 digits

Comment: There's no such thing as `sss` - this is the number of seconds and can only be `s` or `ss` - this is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Can you please explain why you have three digits for the number of seconds? What does that mean?

Comment: I can see now. Thing is that JAVA has "sss" and I'm sending some data to asp.net web service so I put sss also in .NET code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your problem is the 3 digits for seconds in your string:

> 2017-05-01T00:00:000

The range for seconds is `[0:59]`

Either it is milliseconds then you need to adjust your format to :

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTmm:ss:fff";
```

or the string is simply wrong and you should remove the third digit. Here is a working example:

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss";
DateTime parsedDateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("2017-05-01T00:00:00", format, null,
      System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime))
{
     Console.WriteLine(parsedDateTime.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("FAIL");
}
```

Comment: The `'T'` is actually fine - not needed in this case, but fine (having the `'` enclose a string literal within the passed in date string - it is a way to be able and parse date strings that have embedded characters that don't need to be parsed as part of the date/time).

Comment: @DigiFriend you are right, I made a mistake when testing the code. I have removed this part from my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`f` for milliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4):

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-05-01T12:34:567", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssf", null); //700 ms
```

If you need only the date:

```
var d = DateTime.Parse("2017-05-01T12:34:567".Split('T')[0]);
```

or just remove the last digit:

```
var d = DateTime.Parse("2017-05-01T12:34:567".Remove(19));
```